# How to add fields to existing records in CloudKit

Tags: swift, cloudkit, ckrecord, ckmodifyrecordsoperation

I have a function to input a users name into a new recordName in CloudKit (shown below), however I also need to add the users 'score' into the same record.

Is there a way to insert another field "usersScore" by referencing its unique 'recordName' value?

```
/// INSERT NEW ENTRY TO DB.
func insertName(nameEntry: String) -> CKRecordID {

    // Connects to the user database table.
    let userTable = CKRecord(recordType: "User")

    // Connects the Database to the public container.
    let publicData = CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase

    // Adds the users entry into the "name" field.
    userTable["name"] = nameEntry as NSString

    // If the record has saved or an error has occurred.
    publicData.save(userTable) { (record, error) in
        if let saveError = error {
            //Error.
            print("An error occurred in \(saveError)")
        }else {
            // Success.
            print("Saved Record!")
        }
    }
    // RecordName (ID) of the current user.
    recordNameID = userTable.recordID
    return recordNameID!
}
```

Comment: Are you talking about a CKReference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enter multiple records it's better to use`CKModifyRecordsOperation`. 
Here's how I did it...

```
func insertItems(nameEntry: String)  {

    // Creates a record name based on name passed into function.
    let userNamesID = CKRecordID(recordName: "\(nameEntry)")

    // Inserts name into the User table.
    let userName = CKRecord.init(recordType: "User", recordID: userNamesID)

    // Adds the users entry into the "name" field along with score and the amount of questions answered.
    userName["Name"] = nameEntry as CKRecordValue
    userName["Score"] = questionsCorr as CKRecordValue
    userName["Questions_Answered"] = questionsAns as CKRecordValue

    // Insert all records into the database.
    publicDatabase.add(CKModifyRecordsOperation.init(recordsToSave: [userName], recordIDsToDelete: nil))

}
```